# TSQL: Sum from top to bottom of hierarchy

Tags: t-sql, recursive-query

I am trying to do some sort of running total with respect to a multiple level hierarchy.

Sample table. I've added spaces to emphasize the grouping.

```
+----------------+----------------+------------+
|    Manager     |    Employee    |    Cost    |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
| Donald Torres  | Pamela Jordan  | 7,250.78   |
|                |                |            |
| Pamela Jordan  | Harry Rivera   | 36,721.39  |
| Pamela Jordan  | Ryan Mcdonald  | 5,593.89   |
|                |                |            |
| Harry Rivera   | Bruce Mccoy    | 3,538.19   |
|                |                |            |
| Ryan Mcdonald  | Shirley Ortiz  | 137.20     |
| Ryan Mcdonald  | Roger Gardner  | 9,140.34   |
| Ryan Mcdonald  | Paula Richards | 135,109.59 |
|                |                |            |
| Paula Richards | Andrew Boyd    | 106,676.77 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

Desired output

```
+----------------+----------------+------------+
|    Manager     |    Employee    |    Cost    |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
| Donald Torres  | Pamela Jordan  | 304,168.15 |
| Pamela Jordan  | Harry Rivera   | 40,259.58  |
| Pamela Jordan  | Ryan Mcdonald  | 256,657.79 |
| Harry Rivera   | Bruce Mccoy    | 3,538.19   |
| Ryan Mcdonald  | Shirley Ortiz  | 137.20     |
| Ryan Mcdonald  | Roger Gardner  | 9,140.34   |
| Ryan Mcdonald  | Paula Richards | 241,786.36 |
| Paula Richards | Andrew Boyd    | 106,676.77 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

Apologies for giving incorrect desired output. I have already updated the table.

Basically, this is how the hierarchy looks like based on the initial table:

```
Donald Torres                   
    Pamela Jordan               7,250.78
        Harry Rivera            36,721.39
            Bruce Mccoy         3,538.19
        Ryan Mcdonald           5,593.89
            Shirley Ortiz       137.20
            Roger Gardner       9,140.34
            Paula Richards      135,109.59
                Andrew Boyd     106,676.77
```

With regards to the desired output, Paula Richards should get the SUM of Paula Richards(her cost) + Andrew Boyd. Ryan Mcdonald will get the sum of Ryan Mcdonald(hir cost) down to Andrew Boyd. Harry Rivera will only be Harry Rivera + Bruce Mccoy. And lastly Pamela Jordan will get the sum of Pamela Jordan (her cost) down to Andrew Boyd.

I am trying to write the query in SQL 2008R2.

UPDATED: Adding cte base table

```
With Tabl_1 (Manager, Employee, Cost) as (
    Select 'Donald Torres'  , 'Pamela Jordan'  , 7250.78   UNION ALL
    Select 'Pamela Jordan'  , 'Harry Rivera'   , 36721.39  UNION ALL
    Select 'Pamela Jordan'  , 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 5593.89   UNION ALL
    Select 'Harry Rivera'   , 'Bruce Mccoy'    , 3538.19   UNION ALL
    Select 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 'Shirley Ortiz'  , 137.20     UNION ALL
    Select 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 'Roger Gardner'  , 9140.34   UNION ALL
    Select 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 'Paula Richards' , 135109.59 UNION ALL
    Select 'Paula Richards' , 'Andrew Boyd'    , 106676.77
)
```

Comment: The desired output is very confusing.  Why do all of the other groups have a very large cumulative value and then the Harry/Bruce line does not?

Comment: And why is Ryan Mcdonald/Roger Gardner not include the value from Shirley Ortiz?  And how do you determine what the order of Employees for each Manager should be?

Comment: Hi @BaconBits. Determining the order of employees for each manager is also my problem. Not sure if this is achievable using recursive query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trink this query fit your need.

```
With Table_1 (Manager, Employee, Cost) as (
    Select 'Donald Torres'  , 'Pamela Jordan'  , 7250.78   UNION ALL
    Select 'Pamela Jordan'  , 'Harry Rivera'   , 36721.39  UNION ALL
    Select 'Pamela Jordan'  , 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 5593.89   UNION ALL
    Select 'Harry Rivera'   , 'Bruce Mccoy'    , 3538.19   UNION ALL
    Select 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 'Shirley Ortiz'  , 137.20     UNION ALL
    Select 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 'Roger Gardner'  , 9140.34   UNION ALL
    Select 'Ryan Mcdonald'  , 'Paula Richards' , 135109.59 UNION ALL
    Select 'Paula Richards' , 'Andrew Boyd'    , 106676.77
),
CTE as
    (
        select Manager as Manager, Employee as Employee, 1 as Level, Cost as Cost
        from Table_1
        Union All
        select C.Manager, T.Employee, C.Level + 1, T.Cost
        from CTE as C inner join Table_1 as T on C.Employee = T.Manager
    )

select Manager, 
       Employee, 
       T_Cost = Cost + isnull((select SUM(Cost) 
                               from CTE C2 
                               where C2.Manager = C1.Employee)
                             ,0) 
from CTE C1 
where Level = 1
```

Comment: Hi @Polux2. Sorry but It didn't get the desired output.

Comment: @ggarcia You are right, I have corrected my query, sorry.